# How to get all Directories from folder with by date range?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, datetime, directory

I need to get all the directories from a specific folder with date-range like:

### StartDate <= Dir.CreatedDate <= EndDate

I am trying to filter with `GetDirectories` method with no luck:

```
RootDirInfo.GetDirectories()
     .Where(x => new DirectoryInfo(x).CreationTime.Date == DateTime.Today.Date);
```

Comment: What is going wrong? Getting any errors? If so, which?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me split it into functions to make it more clear (and you won't create multiple objects):

```
private static bool IsInRange(DateTime time, DateTime min, DateTime max)
{
    return time >= min && time <= max;
}
```

Now with LINQ you can simply write:

```
public static IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> GetDirectories(
    DirectoryInfo directory,
    DateTime startDate,
    DateTime endDate)
{
    return directory.GetDirectories()
        .Where(x => IsInRange(x.CreationTime, startDate, endDate));
}
```

If you want it compact:

```
public static IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> GetDirectories(
    DirectoryInfo directory,
    DateTime startDate,
    DateTime endDate)
{
    return directory.GetDirectories()
        .Where(x => x.CreationTime >= startDate && x.CreationTime <= endDate);
}
```

Final note: you're doing `new DirectoryInfo(x)` but it wrong because, I suppose `RootDirInfo` is `DirectoryInfo`, then `GetDirectories()` will return `DirectoryInfo[]` ready to use (see my last code snippet).

Answer (score 4):

The type `System.DateTime` does support the operators [`>=`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.datetime.op_greaterthanorequal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`<=`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.datetime.op_lessthanorequal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so you can use those to compare:

```
RootDirInfo.GetDirectories()
    .Where(x => x.CreationTime >= startDate && new x.CreationTime <= endDate);
```

Comment: The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.DirectoryInfo.DirectoryInfo(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @the_farmer I accidentally just used your code without checking, see the edit for the correct way to do this. I forgot that `GetDirectories()` returns the `DirectoryInfo` itself, not the path.